# Why does df.index silently fail when used as a mask in .loc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to set some values in one df (`receiver_df`) using some columns from another df (`send_df`).

Using:

```
receiver_df.loc[send_df.index, stat_clmns_lst] = send_df.iloc[0][stat_col_lst]
```

The code **silently fails**.  `send_df.index` seems to be the problem.

**This process is part of a loop**. So `.join` does not work. On the first pass I do not know all columns that `send_df` is going to pass. Here is how the data looks on the first pass.

#### Setup data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

from IPython.display import display

# Parameters
send_df_index = 2 # Tells send_df where to send data in receiver df
num_rows = 5

# Columns to get from send_df
send_col_lst = ['Some_Index', 'Another_Index']

# Datarame receiving data
receiver_df = pd.DataFrame({'Attempted':[False for x  in range(num_rows)],
                  'StringX':[pd.util.testing.rands(3) for x  in range(num_rows)],
                  'StringY':[pd.util.testing.rands(3) for x  in range(num_rows)]
                  })

# Dataframe sending data
send_values = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=1)
send_values.extend(np.random.uniform(low=2, high=100, size=(1,2)).tolist()[0])

send_df = pd.DataFrame([send_values], 
                        columns=['String', 'Some_Index', 'Another_Index'], 
                        index=[stats_df_index])
```

[image]

#### The script

```
# Reindex - We dont know the stat columns ahead of time
new_col_lst = receiver_df.columns.values.tolist()
new_col_lst.extend(send_col_lst)
receiver_df = receiver_df.reindex(columns=new_col_lst)
```

[image]

```
# Set values to receiving df send_df[stat_col_lst]
receiver_df.loc[send_df.index, send_col_lst] = send_df.iloc[0][send_col_lst]
display(receiver_df)
```

#### Undesired Result:

[image]

#### Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: @Zero Because there are some columns in send_df that overlap with receiver_df but I do not want to use them or merge them.

Comment: @ As for your second solution I tried them but .loc wants a series

Comment: @ Zero I tried both.  Both solutions do not work.  On the second loop `join` adds the `send_df` columns again.  The error in the second solution is `ValueError:: Incompatible indexer with Series`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to make concatenation on axis 1(columns) to work in iteration. Another way to work around it is to append your "Sending df" on axis0 iteratively, then join it to your receiver df after the for loop

```
sending_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(k):
    sending_df = sending_df.append(df2)

receiver_df = receiver_df.join(sending_df)
```